# What http code shall I response if some parameters are not invalid?

Tags: http, rest

I'm creating some restful apis. There is a "register" api, user can POST an "email" and "name" and "password" to register.

On the server side, I will check if the email has been used first. What http code shall I response if I found the email has already been used?

I response 400(bad request) for now, but I don't know if it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`400 Bad Request` is correct since there's no specific HTTP code for validation errors.

In a REST API, in general you only ever need to return four HTTP error codes:

- 401 for unauthorized access
- 404 for unknown resources
- 405 for unsupported methods (eg. GET is available but not POST)
- 400 for everything else

Comment: That is very very misleading, as status codes are an extensibility point, and additional codes, such as 422, 429, or 431, could be applicable.

Comment: @JulianReschke, that's why I wrote "in general". Although I wrote a few web APIs, I never used 422, 429, or 431 but I might some day. You can also indeed return custom 4xx codes but I don't think it's that common either. I guess my answer was the short answer, the long answer is what you mentioned and more.

Comment: To give greater granularity than the blanket '400', you could use 409 'Conflict' to report e.g. a conflict with an email which has already been used, and also 403 'Forbidden' for e.g. validation failure.